# Can short term escalation be applied exceeding life limit on Form 8130-3?

Tags: faa-regulations, aircraft-maintenance

I have a case where there is maintenance item to replace a component when it reaches its life limit. This component life limit is stated on Form 8130-3 of said component referring to component manual. However, maintenance item above is not mentioned as AWL or CMR in aircraft TCDS.

From my understanding, FAA states that short term escalation should not be applied on maintenance item pertaining life limits specified in TCDS. Therefore, for maintenance item above, it is allowed to apply short term escalation (i.e. to postpone component replacement to later date). However, if I do that, the component would exceed life limit on Form 8130-3. Is it allowed to apply short term escalation based on that situation?

Comment: The FAA regional offices have a lot of autonomy and some are stricter than others on regulatory interpretation.  So on those sorts of questions, you might get different answers from different FAA regions.  That's probably something best asked of your local PMI because that's who'll you'll have to answer to in the end.

Comment: *The limitations imposed by OpSpec D076 and the certificate holder’s procedures should not allow a short-term escalation that would compromise the airworthiness of an aircraft or any safety of flight issue. Unanticipated situations arise, such as contractor scheduling, conflicts in weather, parts availability, or other unscheduled maintenance; during which the short-term escalation of a maintenance interval may be used*  What is the purpose behind requesting the escalation?